# Unable to load ViewComponent through jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-2.0

The ViewComponent code:

```
public class EducationShowViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private databaseContext _dbContext = new databaseContext();

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string candidateId)
    {
        var educations = _dbContext.Candidates.Include(j => j.CandidateEducations)
           .Single(j => j.UserId == candidateId)
           .CandidateEducations;

        return View(educations);
    }
}
```

The component container which is loading the component fine on page load:

```
<div class="edu-history-sec">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("EducationShow") , new { candidateId = ViewBag.InvokeEducationWithId })
</div>
```

But it's not working when I try to reload the container by using `$.get`.

```
$('.loadview').on('click', function () {
    alert('before $.get'); // OK
    $.get('/Candidate/EducationShowViewComponent/1012', function (data) {
        alert('inside $.get'); // not executing
        $('.edu-history-sec').html(data);
    });
});
```

The Action code of the Candidate controller

```
public IActionResult EducationShowViewComponent(string id)
{
    return ViewComponent("EducationShow", new { candidateId = id });
}
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong, I've been stuck in this for 2 whole days not being able to make it work!?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using the wrong parameter name. Use `new { candidateId= id }` in your action method.

Comment: Hi @Shyju, I apologize for that one, the parameter name is correct in my project, I must have wrote it wrong when I posted the question here. I have also tried to debug it, the controller is calling the ViewComponent and everything is working fine til it comes to the client side.

Comment: Check the devtools->network tab and see whether the call is made. If yes, see the response tab. My feeling is, your code is crashing because you are passing an invalid `UserId` . Is `1012` a valid `UserId` ? If not your code will crash because Single will throw an exception.

Comment: 1012 is the Id of my favorite testing candidate. What I did is modified the Action code to:

Comment: Did you check the browser console / network tab ? Is it making the call ? What is the response you are getting ?

Comment: Edit:
1012 is the Id of my favorite testing candidate. What I did is modified the Action code to:
            var vc = ViewComponent("EducationShow", new { candidateId = id });
            return vc;
and I put a breakpoint on the returning row to check the value of the vc variable. The ViewComponent is working fine since the same one is returning data on page load for that specific Id but I think that the data to the controller are not being passed correctly.

Comment: Did you read me previous comment ?

Comment: Yes, it is making the call. The Response section of the Network tab says that this request has no response data available

Comment: Right click on the call and select "open in new tab". that should open that url in a new tab. Put breaking point in your Invoke method code and see what it is executing

Comment: I did exactly as you said, it's finding 7 records in the database for the candidate Id provided and it's returning the `educations` collection filled with those records, but what I find weird is the order of the code being executed:
   - var vc = ViewComponent("EducationShow", new { jobseekerId = id }); 
   - return vc;
and then after the viewcomponent is returned, the Invoke method is being called.

Comment: It should execute the view for the view component and return the HTML.

Comment: Shouldn't the order of the execution be: 
1: (Controller) var vc = ViewComponent("EducationShow", new { jobseekerId = id });
2: (ViewComponent) public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string candidateId) { }
3: (Controller) return vc;  ?

Comment: The action code you shared in your question should work fine.

Comment: It's not working :( The first test `alert` from the jQuery code is executing, but the second one within the $.get function is not. But thanks for trying mate, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Shyju you were right, I just changed `return View(educations);` to `return Content("Test Content");` within the `Invoke()` method of the `ViewComponent` and I get "Test Content" within the html container, so the problem is not to the jQuery call, it seems to be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call it by `$.get("EducationShow/Invoke", (html) => {...})`

The only problem I see, is that you will receive the complete html page not only the "partial view"